# Spark MLin Word2vec

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am trying to run Spark MLlibs word2vec implementation.I am using scala for this.My input for the model is Array of Sequence of strings.It looks as shown below

```
scala> f.take(5)
res11: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([WrappedArray(0_42)], [WrappedArray(big, baller, shoe, ?)], [WrappedArray(since, eliud, win, ,, quick, fact, from, runner, from, country, kalenjins, !, write, ., happy, quick, fact, kalenjins, location, :, kenya, (, kenya's, western, highland, rift, valley, ), population, :, 4, ., 9, million, ;, compose, 11, subtribes, language, :, kalenjin, ;, swahili, ;, english, church, :, christianity, ~, africa, inland, church, [, aic, ],, church, province, kenya, [, cpk, ],, roman, catholic, church, ;, islam, translation, :, kalenjin, translate, ", tell, ", formation, :, wwii, ,, gikuyu, tribal, member, wish, separate, create, identity, ., later, ,, student, attend, alliance, high, school, (, first, british, public, school, kenya, ), form, tribe, become, future, kal...

val v=f.map(l=>Seq(l.toString))
scala> v.take(5)
res31: Array[Seq[String]] = Array(List([WrappedArray(0_42)]), List  ([WrappedArray(big, baller, shoe, ?)]), List([WrappedArray(since, eliud, win, ,, quick, fact, from, runner, from, country, kalenjins, !, write, ., happy, quick, fact, kalenjins, location, :, kenya, (, kenya's, western, highland, rift, valley, ), population, :, 4, ., 9, million, ;, compose, 11, subtribes, language, :, kalenjin, ;, swahili, ;, english, church, :, christianity, ~, africa, inland, church, [, aic, ],, church, province, kenya, [, cpk, ],, roman, catholic, church, ;, islam, translation, :, kalenjin, translate, ", tell, ", formation, :, wwii, ,, gikuyu, tribal, member, wish, separate, create, identity, ., later, ,, student, attend, alliance, high, school, (, first, british, public, school, kenya, ), form, ....
```

Each sentence is in a separate list as shown above.I run the model by giving v as the input

```
scala> val model = word2vec.fit(v)
```

But the output of this model does not look to be proper. When I save the model and try to read its parquet file(a) I get the below results.

```
   model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
   val a=sqlContext.read.parquet("myModelPath")
   a.show(20,false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|word                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(coffee, machine)]                                     |
|[WrappedArray(good, experience)]                                    |
|[WrappedArray(love, room, !)]                                       |
|[WrappedArray(parking, .)]                                          |
|[WrappedArray(breakfast, great, !)]                                 |
|[WrappedArray(bed, comfortable, room, spacious, .)]                 |
```

This word2vec model instead of creating the vectors for each word is creating vectors for array of words.
I am not sure what is the correct way of feeding input to this model and how does it break sentences or words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet that if you look at `v.first` you'll see `List([WrappedArray(0_42)])` and if you look at `v.first.head` you'll see `[WrappedArray(0_42)]`.  But `v.first.head` is a String, and what you're actually seeing is `"[WrappedArray(0_42)]"`.  There is no WrappedArray, just a string.  Perhaps you accidentally called `toString` on a `WrappedArray` (or fell victim to an implicit conversion to String).  Word2Vec is actually seeing strings like `"[WrappedArray(coffee, machine)]"` in its input, and generating a model based on those strings.

UPDATE

If I have your types right, f is a `DataFrame` where each `Row` contains a single field holding a `Seq[String]` (which is actually a `WrappedArray`).

So, instead of

```
val v=f.map(l=>Seq(l.toString))
```

what you should be doing to extract that field is

```
val v = f.map(r => r.getSeq[String](0))
```

This produces a `Dataset[Seq[String]]` that should be suitable for input to `Word2Vec`.

Comment: Yes you are right I have called tostring on a wrappedArray. I had to convert an Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to Seq[String].I have edited the question to show you my   operations.Can you guide me whats the right way to convert this input

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggested approach.